# Laravel relationship doesn't return data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get my data in table by ajax and it's successfull but some of data are id of other tabels and those data i cannot get somehow!

## Example

Sample data returned by JS:

```
customers":[
    {
        "id":2,
        "group_id":3,
        "industry_id":2,
        "name":"fwgvwrg",
        "companyName":"bget"
    }
]
```

In this data if i use like: `i.group.name (same as in blade if we say {{$customer->group->name}}` for `group_id` it returns error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Basically there is no issue from JS it's about my models relations here are my models:

**Customer model**

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(GroupCustomer::class, 'id', 'group_id');
}

public function industry()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Industry::class);
}
```

**Groups model**

```
public function customers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class, 'id', 'group_id');
}
```

**Industry model**

```
public function customers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::class);
}
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is your model relationship about foreign key parameter position:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(GroupCustomer::class, 'group_id', 'id');
}
```

[See model doc here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Blade** view you can call laravel relationship directly. it will work fine.

but in **Js** it won't work. you can't call relationship

so when you have to use **with()** like below

```
Ex : Customer::with('group')->get();
```